# python pandas: how to loop over dateframe and add columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need a loop to do what this code is doing and automatically generate columns ep1 ep2 and so on..

```
df['ep1'] = df.ep1.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x.year,x.month,1))
df['ep2'] = df.ep1.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime((x+datetime.timedelta(days=40)).year,(x+datetime.timedelta(days=40)).month,1))
df['ep3'] = df.ep2.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime((x+datetime.timedelta(days=40)).year,(x+datetime.timedelta(days=40)).month,1))
```

where the ep vector is the first day of months between df.opdate and df.closdate.

as a start

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
d = {'closdate' : pd.Series([datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 2), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 2)]),'opdate' : pd.Series([datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1)])}

df=pd.DataFrame(d)

df['ep1'] = df.opdate.apply(lambda x: x if x > datetime.datetime(2014,1,1) else datetime.datetime(2014,1,1))
df['ep1'] = df.ep1.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x.year,x.month,1))
df['ep2'] = df.ep1.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime((x+datetime.timedelta(days=40)).year,(x+datetime.timedelta(days=40)).month,1))
df['ep3'] = df.ep2.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime((x+datetime.timedelta(days=40)).year,(x+datetime.timedelta(days=40)).month,1))
```

How do i loop until ep is larger than the df.closdate?

Comment: Why are you repeating the same operation to create `df['ep1']` and why are you creating `ep1` and `ep2` columns that are equivalent?

Comment: Is your goal to create columns whose days are `previous column's date + 1 month`?

Comment: I need it to advance by a month.  ep2 should be one month (but still first day of that month) ahead of ep1, as long as it fits inside the op and close values of that row

Comment: the real data set will expand by 30 to unknown months, and i need something that creates columns e.g. "ep%s" % counter, and i have no idea where to look for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `where` instead of `apply` and add days with `np.timedelta64`

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import Timestamp

months = range(1, 13)
df['ep0'] = df.opdate.where(df.opdate > Timestamp('20140101'), Timestamp('20140101'))
for month in months:
    colname = 'ep%d' % month
    prev_colname = 'ep%d' % (month - 1)
    df[colname] = df[prev_colname] + np.timedelta64(40, 'D')
```

Comment: wow. that's great.  I need study this! is there an easy way to reset the new column to the first day?

Comment: You can access the `df.index`'s `year`, `month`, `day`, etc attributes and manually reset it similar to what you're doing above.